# Send and process form data

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a form that I would like to send to saveConfig.php so that the data can be saved into a MySQL database. I would like to pass the selected form options, as well as the total.

```
<form id="configSave" action="" class="hide-submit">
<div class="btn-configure" id="configSave">
<span class="pcButtonText">
Save
</span>                                               
</div>

<ul id="radio" class="input-list">
  <li>
    <input id="item-1" name="config-prod" value="1.00" type="radio" onchange="updateTotal();">
    <label for="item-1">Item 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item-2" name="config-prod" value="2.00" type="radio" onchange="updateTotal();">
    <label for="item-2">Item 2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item-3" name="config-prod" value="3.00" type="radio" onchange="updateTotal();">
    <label for="item-3">Item 3</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<select id="plist" name="partlist" onchange="save();">
  <option value="99.99">CPU 1</option>
  <option value="123.00">CPU 2</option>
  <option value="250.54">CPU 3</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
Total: <input id="total" type="text">

<script>
        $('#configSave').on('click', function () {
            alert("ok");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'saveConfig.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#configSave').serialize(),
                dataType: "JSON",
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('saved');
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Within the PHP file, how can I access the form data so I can save it into the database?
I get this error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means the JSON string that is arriving at the PHP server is malformed. The reason it is malformed is because you cannot serialize a `<div>`. The serialize method is designed to serialize form elements [Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Change:

```
data: $('#configSave').serialize(),
```

To:

```
data: $('#form').serialize(),
```